# Android build error when implementing google places sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, google-places-autocomplete

Hello everyone I am developing simple food delivery android application so its required to integrate google maps and auto suggestion I follow to find current location

```
[google sample code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap/app/src/main/java/com/example/currentplacedetailsonmap/MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java)
```

and for Auto suggestions I followed

```
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete
```

when build it gradle shows duplicate class error

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.api.internal.impl.net.pablo.AutocompletePredictionResult found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.api.internal.impl.net.pablo.AutocompletePredictionResult$StructuredFormatting found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.api.internal.impl.net.pablo.AutocompletePredictionResult$Substring found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.api.internal.impl.net.pablo.FetchPlacePabloResponse found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)

Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.bc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.bd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.be found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0)
```

And this my gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

i try to exclude duplicate classes by below way

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'){
 exclude group:'com.google.android.libraries.places.api.internal.impl.net.pablo'
 exclude group: 'com.google.android.libraries.places.internal'
    }
```

But no thing can solve my problem.

Comment: Why do you use placescompat?

Comment: use `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1`

Comment: @Sajith Nope. that library will be deprecated by July 29,2019

Answer (score 1):

**Remove** 
 `implementation'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'`

and keep only `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'`.

> Using `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'`
>
> is neccessary only if you are using deprecated library of
>
> `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'`

Please take a look [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/95) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places).

Comment: But i want find user current location but these classes not resolves "PlaceDetectionClient" and Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null);

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places

Comment: -"getGeoDataClient", This method was deprecated.
use getGeoDataClient(Context) instead.
-"getPlaceDetectionClient", This method was deprecated.
use getPlaceDetectionClient(Context) instead

Comment: If you find it helpful upvote and select the answer, so it will be useful for other developers.

Comment: @JogiPrasadPakki If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: What should I do if I want to use PlacePicker from the compat library?

Comment: @ekar in that case you use the compat library.